# Alternative to unifiedFile in EPIServer 10

Tags: episerver

Is there anyone expert in EPIServer. I need help to migrate code from Version 6 to 10. I have this code in my file and it gives error after i migrated to Version 10.

```
  public void Initialize(InitializationEngine context)
    {
        UnifiedFile.UnifiedFileCheckedIn += UnifiedFile_UnifiedFileCheckedIn;
    }
```

It gives error on UnifiedFile.The name unifiedfile does not exist in current context. Like this many errors related to it. What is alternative for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The media system was changed in EPiServer 7.5. You have to migrate your data and rewrite code for it to work in EPiServer 10.

http://world.episerver.com/documentation/upgrading/Episerver-CMS/75/Migrating-VPP-based-files-to-the-new-media-system/

http://world.episerver.com/documentation/developer-guides/CMS/Content/assets-and-media2/

There is no direct equivalent of checking in files but there are a number of events that you could subscribe to to run your code. You can get an instance of IContentEvents in your Initialize method and add an event handler for the SavedContent event like this:

```
public void Initialize(InitializationEngine context)
{
   context.Locate.Advanced.GetInstance<IContentEvents>().SavedContent =+    DoStuffWithSavedContent;
}

    private void DoStuffWithSavedContent(object sender, ContentEventArgs e)
    {
     // Do stuff here...
    }
```

A description of all the events available is here:

http://world.episerver.com/documentation/class-library/?documentId=cms/7/306eae4b-2ba2-dd1e-c114-bccb0d3d2968

Here are more examples of working with media:

http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/Developers-Guide/Episerver-CMS/9/Content/Assets-and-media/Working-with-media/

Comment: So i need to throw away all code referencing unifiedfile, unifieddirectory?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. The data can be migrated using EPiServers migration tool for VPP to media but the code needs to be manually fixed.

Comment: my colleague told that data is migrated but code needs to be changed. Which code example i can refer to?

Comment: I edited my answer with an example of how to run code responding to events. Which specific event you want to use depends on the code you have.

Comment: Old code had below lines which refer to virtualpathprovider and unifiedirectory   var sourcePath = AdImportSettings.Instance.EmployeePhotoPath;

     var dir = HostingEnvironment.VirtualPathProvider.GetDirectory(sourcePath) as UnifiedDirectory;

Comment: what could be equivalent of this?

Comment: I'm not going to rewrite all the code for you. Read the documentation. I added a link to the section in the documentation about working with media. To get a folder you have to get a ContentReference to the folder. In your case you have the path to a folder so I would create the same folder structure in the new media library and then get the folder ContentReference (the ID of the folder). From the ContentReference you can use the IContentLoader to get the children or descendants as ContentFolder and MediaData objects and work from there.